# MongoDB + NodeJS + Express - User can send friend request to someone who is already their friend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I currently have a user system where users can add each other as friend. This is my route:

```
app.post("/addFriend", function(req, res) {
var conditions = {
    $or: [
        {$and: [
            {username: req.body.globalUserName},
            {$or: [
                {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id}},
                {'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id}}
            ]}
        ]},
        {$and: [
            {username: req.user.username},
            {$or: [
                {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.body.globalUserId}},
                {'friends._id': {$ne: req.body.globalUserId}}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
}
var update = {
    $addToSet: {pendingFriends: { _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, language: req.user.language, profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture}}
}

User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, function(error, doc) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(currentTime + " - FRIEND_REQUEST_SEND_ERROR: '" + req.user.username + "' TRIED TO SEND A FRIEND REQUEST TO '" + req.body.globalUserName + "'");
        }
        else {
            console.log(currentTime + " - FRIEND_REQUEST_SENT: '" + req.user.username + "' SENT A FRIEND REQUEST TO '" + req.body.globalUserName + "'");
        }
        res.redirect("/talk");
    });
});
```

So this is how it works.

U1 sends a friend request to U2.

U1 gets added to U2's pendingFriends.

If U2 accepts, U1 goes to U2's friends and U2 goes to U1's friends.

However, I have two bugs right now that I know of.

If U1 sends a friend request to U2, while U1 is in U2's pendingFriends, U2 can send a friend request to U1.

Also, if U1 sends a friend request to U2, after U2 accepts, both U1 and U2 can send friend requests to each other still.

How do I fix this? By the way, req.user is the user performing the actions (sending the form, etc.). req.body.globalUserId is the id of the user that the user performing the actions is trying to add.

EDIT (user schema by request of user):

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email:  String,
    password: String,
    language: { type: String, default: "English" },
    profilePicture: { type: String, default: "/images/talk/blank-profile-picture.png" },
    status: String,
    pendingFriends: [this],
    friends: [this]
})
```

Comment: i think it is because of the or operation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it! Here is my code:

```
app.post("/addFriend", function(req, res) {
    var pendingIds, friendIds;
    if (req.user.pendingFriends.length > 0) {
        pendingIds = new Array(req.user.pendingFriends.length - 1);
        req.user.pendingFriends.forEach(function (pendingFriend) {
            pendingIds.push(pendingFriend._id);
            console.log("Pending friend id: " + pendingFriend._id);
        })
    }
    if (req.user.friends.length > 0) {
        friendIds = new Array(req.user.friends.length - 1);
        req.user.friends.forEach(function (friend) {
            friendIds.push(friend._id);
            console.log("Friend id: " + friend._id);
        })
    }
    var conditions = {
        $or: [
            {$and: [
                {_id: {$nin: pendingIds}}, // not a pending friend of U2
                {_id: {$nin: friendIds}},        // not a friend of U2
                {username: req.body.globalUserName},
                {'pendingFriends._id.toString()': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}}, // U2 is not a pending friend
                {'friends._id.toString()': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}}         // U2 is not a friend
            ]}
        ]
    }
    var update = {
        $addToSet: {pendingFriends: { _id: req.user._id.toString(), username: req.user.username, language: req.user.language, profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture}}
    }

    User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, function(error, doc) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(currentTime + " - FRIEND_REQUEST_SEND_ERROR: '" + req.user.username + "' TRIED TO SEND A FRIEND REQUEST TO '" + req.body.globalUserName + "'");
        }
        else {
            console.log(currentTime + " - FRIEND_REQUEST_SENT: '" + req.user.username + "' SENT A FRIEND REQUEST TO '" + req.body.globalUserName + "'");
        }
        res.redirect("/talk");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Russell, If feasible can you please help me with your User schema. I am also working on the same functionality so I want to see how your user schema looks like. That would be a great help.

Comment: @HemadriDasari Sure! I edited my original post and put my User schema as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

U1 = user with username => req.body.globalUserName

U2 = logged in user

query finds:

```
U1 IF U2 is not a pending friend OR U2 is not a friend
```

OR

```
U2 IF U1 is not a pending friend OR U1 is not a friend
```

Update will find only one of those users, and add U1 to their pendingFriends
for example, if U2 sends a request to U1, and U1 does not exist in the system, U2 will add themself to their own pendingfriends

We dont actually want to find U2, we just want to make sure U1 is not a friend/pendingfriend of U2.

A correct query would be along the lines of

```
let U2PendingFriendIds = array of all U2's pending friends ids
let U2FriendIds = array of all U2's friends ids

var conditions = {
    $or: [
        {$and: [
            {_id: {$nin: U2PendingFriendIds}, // not a pending friend of U2
            {_id: {$nin: U2FriendIds},        // not a friend of U2
            {username: req.body.globalUserName}, 
            {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id}}, // U2 is not a pending friend
            {'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id}}         // U2 is not a friend
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One resource that I've just recently found is an npm module that facilitates all friendship functionality. You can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-friends

I realize you already have your code setup to add friends, but this module may be an alternative method of attack to help make your code less of a hassle to deal with and simpler to read. Only if that interests you though.